# Have Mossbauer spectroscopy on 67Zn ever been used to study Zinc containing enzymes?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, enzymes

Have Mossbauer spectroscopy with 67Zn as absorber and 67Ga as emitter ever been used to study zinc containing enzymes?
The perfect answer will contain link to article/book where example of 67Zn usage is given or article/book where author tells that there is no such thing yet.

Comment: A quick literature search for titles with 'Mossbauer'+'enzyme' came up with only Fe Mossbauer stuff (and not much of that). On the other hand, I could have missed something in the list, or it just doesn't appear in the title.

Comment: Same here. It turns out that proving something do not exist is much harder than proving something do exist.

Comment: Indeed! So, the question to ask is: Do you want to do the experiment because nobody else has, or do you want to do the experiment to learn something in particular about an enzyme? Either way is fine, but be clear to yourself what your purpose is.

Comment: As far as I can see: yes. I've just googled it. And still: if it's not on google someone could still have done it before.

[Zn-exchange and Mossbauer studies on the [Fe-Fe] derivatives
of the purple acid Fe(II1)-Zn(I1)-phosphatase from kidney beans](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1432-1033.1993.tb17926.x/pdf).

Comment: @AmelieB.Blackstone In that article, the Mossbauer aspect refers to the Fe atoms.

Comment: You can directly contact Mossbauer labs specialised in the field, if you want to be sure. I see some problems here: 1) enzyme samples are very diluted, and it is very hard to make even the iron experiments, 2) the payoff is much smaller than in the case of iron. Iron has several oxydation and spin states, several of them are paramagnetic, therefore Mossbauer is rather informative. Zn spectra would give much less intersting data.